# How to arrange java code in proper way

Tags: java

the code in .java file is not arranged or not in a formatted way.
Can anyone suggest me a software that can format or arrange the code in good manner.
for e.g. I have code like this...

```
class a{ public static void main(String s []){}}
```

but i want it arrange in a proper way like this

```
class a{

      public static void main(String s[]){
      }
}
```

Comment: Any IDE? Jalopy? Etc.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Some of them, like `Eclipse` have built in procedures that will do it for you

Comment: Use your IDE's auto formatter.

Comment: If you only want to open a `.java` file and see code arranged properly I suggest you `Notepad++`. But if you're in a development process you should use an IDE like `Eclipse` or `NetBeans`.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to use Netbeans, you will get these advantages,

- Formatting your code properly is very easy in Netbeans
- If you make a new class, The class is shown with all formatting done,

Comment: any particular objective reason to choose this one? The features you have listed seem to be common to most IDEs. We want objective answers here.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Objective when it comes to *tooling*? No way, will never happen. Nerds are still fighting vi vs. Emacs wars, and it will never end.

Comment: @Jason that's why I voted to clo... er, put on hold this question. C'mon, just one more vote...

Comment: yes there is a reason to choose netbeans other than any other IDE, The reason is that it has some new ways for developing, For e.g It's drag and drop tool and the second one is it's extendable features through Plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

Most IDEs these days (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, ...) have code formatting capabilities built into them. They have many options to setup the exact style for you.

If you are not using an IDE, get one, Eclipse is free!  :)

Or you could try something like [Jalopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jalopy/)  (it's a free version of a similar tool: JIndent)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the code you have copied has line breaks that are not compatible with your OS.

I would recommend getting an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse and putting the code there, as they have linebreak adapters.

No need to manually insert your native linebreaks.

Comment: the java code is stored in the database as text format....how i can print it in a formatted way on console.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Eclipse IDE.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Eclispe has a default integrated code formatter and you are able to customize this feature:

http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipseide/source_formatting/

You can also say eclipse to performe code formatting everytime you safe or run the code, so you normaly never need to format code by yourself.

Alternativly you could use netbeans, which is an open source ide as well which supports code formatting.

Comment: any particular objective reason to choose this one? We want objective answers here.

Comment: I want to print the java code in a file...not on ide.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that, eclipse no only shows the code formatted it also change the file content so you can open it with notepad++ for example and still got the formatted code

Comment: the java code is stored in the database as text format....how i can print it in a formatted way on console.